# MySQL Insert Into Complex Statement

Tags: mysql

I'm on the path of:

```
INSERT INTO family (family_id, member_id)
VALUES (maxfamily, membersid)
(SELECT member_id as membersid, (MAX(family_id)+1) as maxfamily
FROM members
GROUP BY lname
HAVING COUNT (lname)>1)
```

Current error: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT member_id as membersid, (MAX(family_id)+1) as maxfamily FROM member' at line 3

I'm assuming this is from MAX(family_id) as it doesn't know the current max number from having no reference given to the family table?

Intention:

Find from the members table people with the same last name. Use this query to insert new records into the family table.

```
Example:
members table
Andersen, Fred, id=288
Andersen, Smith, id=289
Smith, Peter, id=385
Smith, Elizabeth, id=404
Williams, Kevin, id=408

family table (currently empty)
family_id, member_id
1, 288
1, 289 (this covers the Anderson family)
2, 385
2, 404 (this covers the Smith family)
```

Question: How do I create the correct query for this task? Note that the family id is auto incremented based on the last maximum value.

I know how to do it in programming I just would like to do it in direct SQL.

The Williams name is ignored because it doesn't have a matching last name.

TIA

Comment: Well not this one, for a start you trying are selecting 3 values into 2 fields. Count to 10 and start again

Comment: You need to replace the `VALUES (maxfamily, membersid)` with a select that returns 2 values. The where clause is irrelevant

Comment: if the family_id is auto_incremented how can you have multiple rows of the same family_id?

Comment: Still fighting with it. Just giving SQL errors currently. family_id isn't auto incremented as it's not the table's unique index. It's just an index which allows dups.

Answer (score 2):

give this a try.

```
SET @prev_lname = '', @id = 0;
INSERT INTO family(family_id,member_id)
SELECT family_id, id
FROM
  (SELECT members.lname,members.id,
       CASE WHEN @prev_lname = members.lname THEN @id
            ELSE @id := IFNULL(@id,0) + 1
            END as family_id,
       @prev_lname := members.lname
  FROM 
  members,(SELECT lname
            FROM members
            GROUP BY lname
            HAVING COUNT(*)>1) AS qualify
WHERE members.lname = qualify.lname
ORDER BY members.lname ASC
)AS T;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0c1b/1)

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'members.id' in 'field list' the member table has a field called member_id. I was trying to follow your statement but I don't see how members_id is brought up from the second query. Thanks for your help I was thinking I was missing a third query. Now I start to see it.

Comment: then just replace occurrences of `id` with `member_id`

Answer (score 1):

1) Get the family names:

```sql
select lname
from members
group by lname
having count(lname) > 1;
```

2) Enumerate the family last names:

```sql
select lname, (@fid := @fid + 1) as family_id
from members, (select @fid := 0) dummy
group by lname
having count(lname) > 1;
```

3) Join with the members table on lname:

```sql
select f.family_id, m.member_id
from (
    select lname, (@fid := @fid + 1) as family_id
    from members, (select @fid := 0) dummy
    group by lname
    having count(lname) > 1
) f
join members m on m.lname = f.lname;
```

4) **Result** (Create the insert statement):

```sql
insert into family (family_id, member_id)
    select f.family_id, m.member_id
    from (
        select lname, (@fid := @fid + 1) as family_id
        from members, (select @fid := 0) dummy
        group by lname
        having count(lname) > 1
    ) f
    join members m on m.lname = f.lname
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/209a55/2